# How can clear $timeout in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, timeout, angularjs-timeout

I have this code for image slider and next prev and auto change the image function

```
scope.next = function () {
    scope.currentIndex < scope.images.length - 1 ? scope.currentIndex++ : scope.currentIndex = 0;
};

scope.prev = function () {
    scope.currentIndex > 0 ? scope.currentIndex-- : scope.currentIndex = scope.images.length - 1;
};

scope.$watch('currentIndex', function () {
    scope.images.forEach(function (image) {
    image.visible = false;
    });

    scope.images[scope.currentIndex].visible = true;
});

var timer;
var sliderFunc = function () {
    timer = $timeout(function () {
        scope.next();
        timer = $timeout(sliderFunc, 5000);
    }, 5000);
};

sliderFunc();

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
});
```

and in slider template I have the arrows link for next and prev function

```
  <div class="arrows">
    <a href="#" ng-click="prev()">
      <img src="tasavir/omgh/left-arrow.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="next()">
      <img src="tasavir/omgh/right-arrow.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

I just want to add clear $timeout function when user click on the next or prev btn and each time the user click on the next or prev btn the timer was clear and change image in 5s later.

this is the full doc about [image slider](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-slide-show-plugin-angularjs/)

I create the JSFiddle for this [please look at this](https://jsfiddle.net/hemedani/8cLw6wch/15/)

Comment: Why do you use timeout inside timeout? Maybe you shoud use $interval?

Comment: please do that in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hemedani/8cLw6wch/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Roman and @Pankaj for helping. I fixed it with this code:

```js
scope.next = function() {
    $interval.cancel(timer);
    scope.changeImage(); // just add this line
    timer = $interval(function() {
        scope.changeImage();
    }, 5000);
};
```

In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/8cLw6wch/22/) version of @Roman edited.

[The Final version](https://jsfiddle.net/8cLw6wch/23/)

Answer (score 3):

This is my third try: https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/8cLw6wch/22/

```js
var timer = $interval(function () {
    scope.changeImage();
}, 5000);

scope.next = function () {
    $interval.cancel(timer);

    timer = $interval(function () {
        scope.changeImage();
    }, 5000);
};

scope.changeImage = function () {
    scope.currentIndex < scope.images.length - 1
        ? scope.currentIndex++
        : (scope.currentIndex = 0);
};
```

Comment: tnx, but you cancel the timer and did not change image automatic when using the next btn

Comment: I don't understand you. When i clicked on the next btn, an image changes once  and interval  canceled.

Comment: see, we want the interval cleared when we click on the next btn, when we several time click on the next btn the interval did not cleared in the 5s second we clicked the next and image changed in that second interval changed the image too, so 2 imaged was slides

Comment: in fact we want every time we clicked on the next btn the interval was stop and restart again and changed image in 5 second later

Answer (score 2):

You could do by setting timeout from `$scope.next` function by checking a flag.

**Markup**

```
<div class="arrows">
    <a href="#" ng-click="prev()">
      <img src="tasavir/omgh/left-arrow.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="next(true)">
      <img src="tasavir/omgh/right-arrow.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
var timer;
var sliderFunc = function () {
    timer = $timeout(function () {
        scope.next(false);
    }, 5000);
};

scope.next = function(setTimeoutToNext){
    scope.currentIndex < scope.images.length - 1 ? scope.currentIndex++ : scope.currentIndex = 0;
    if(setTimeoutToNext)
      $timeout.cancel(timer); //here it will clear the timeout
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8cLw6wch/21/)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately did note resolve the problem, I created JSFiddle for this please take a look at that and fixed in that tanx https://jsfiddle.net/hemedani/8cLw6wch/14/

Comment: @SydAmir look at the edit..Now it fixed I wrote different line instead of `$timeout.cancel(timer)`